# Getting value from <select> statement from jsp to Action class

Tags: jsp

I have the following `<select>..</select>` in my code:

```
<select name="approvername">
    <option value="first name">my first name</option>
    <option value="second name">my second name</option>
    <option value="third name">my third name</option>
    <option value="fourth name">my fourth name</option>
</select>
```

When I try to get the value in my action class,like `String approvername = request.getParameter("approvername")` it shows null when I try to print it.

How to get the value?

Comment: Is the select in html form ?

Comment: Yes it is in the <form> of course.
But I get null value when I try to print it suing
String approvername = request.getParameter("approvername") in my java class

Comment: Any idea what should be the problem with my above code?

Comment: Looking at the code you provided there don't seems to be any issue, it should work. Can you post the html form and servlet code ?

Comment: @cya k which server side technology you are using

Comment: I answered my question. Just check my answer. I just had to modify it as
String approvername = (String)areq.getParameter("approvername");  instead of
String approvername = request.getParameter("approvername")
Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action class instead of using

```
String approvername = request.getParameter("approvername")
```

I've changed it to

```
String approvername = (String)areq.getParameter("approvername");
```

And it works!!

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference.

Comment: You don't need to cast. getParameter method returns String

Comment: Originally I was trying String approvername = request.getParameter("approvername").
Now I used :
String approvername = (String)areq.getParameter("approvername");
which converts the parameter to String. I did not understand why this had to make a difference since getParameter accepts only String. But initially when I was trying to get values from combobox it was printing null..

Comment: Exactly Abdullah. I know we do not need to cast since getParameter returns string. but initially it was showing me null but when I cast it,it shows me the value.

Comment: Any idea why should this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this for this type of select is to use `getParameterValues`. You will get an array of strings with all the values selected, in your case it will only be an array with 1 element.

```
String approvername = request.getParameterValues("approvername")[0].
```